# How can I train a sequential model in keras, giving a list as outputs and inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am very new to Keras and to machine learning in general, but here is what I want. I have a list of inputs (1 value for every input node) and a list of targets (1 value for every output node).

```
    input_list = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] # maybe longer

    wanted_output_list = [1, 0, 0, 0] # also maybe longer
```

And now I want to give these as input to train my neural network:

```
    # create model
    model = Sequential()

    # get number of columns in training data
    n_cols = 6

    # add model layers
    model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu', input_shape= (n_cols,)))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3))

    # compile the model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

    # train model
    model.fit(input_list, wanted_output_list, validation_split=0.2, epochs=30)
```

However I get this error:

```
    ValueError: Error when checking input: dense_1_input to have shape (6,) but got with shape (1,)
```

Can anyone please tell me why and how I can fix this?

Comment: You are trying to train a model that need an input with 6 features. Does each of your datapoints has 6 features ? Your input should be a 2D array, with a shape [?,6]. If you convert your example to `[[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]`, it should work.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, unfortunately I still get the same error after I changed what you said.

Comment: Are you saying your network has multiple FEATURES, or multiple INPUTS nodes and OUTPUT nodes?

Comment: You last dense layer should match your output count . If you want to predict 6 values - your last layer should be Dense(6), not Dense(3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining your model, you specified a model that accepts an input with 6 features, and output a vector with 3 component. You training data, however, is not shaped correctly (nor your labels, by the way). You should shape your data the way you have defined your model. In this case, that means that each sample of your training data is a vector with 6 components, and each label is a vector with 3 components.

Keras expects a list of `numpy array` (or a 2D array) when training a model with multiple inputs, see the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit).

> **x** : Input data. It could be:
>
> - A Numpy array (or array-like), or a list of arrays (in case the model has multiple inputs).

So per your model definition, you could shape your training data the following way :

```
import numpy as np
# your data, in this case 2 datapoints
X = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
# the corresponding labels
y = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]])
```

And then train your model by calling `fit`.

```
model.fit(x, y, epochs=30)
```

Comment: Not sure this is what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually asking about having multiple input and outputs as opposed to multiple features (not the same thing) then this cannot be done using the Sequential API and instead you must use the [Keras Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/). Here you can define multiple inputs and outputs and then pass those as a list as you suggested.

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58232724/7604321) on a this topic from last week may also be of assistance.

Answer (score -2):

Please convert your input features and classes to arrays and set number of nodes in last layer to number of classes in `y`.
Refer the code below:

```
X = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])

y = np.array([[1, 0, 0,0]])

model = Sequential()

n_cols = 6

model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu', input_shape= (n_cols,)))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(5))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

model.fit(X, y, epochs=30)
```