# How to optimize multiple loss functions separately in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am currently trying to build a deep learning model with three different loss functions in Keras. The first loss function is the typical mean squared error loss. The other two loss functions are the ones I built myself, which finds the difference between a calculation made from the input image and the output image (this code is a simplified version of what I'm doing).

```
def p_autoencoder_loss(yTrue,yPred):

    def loss(yTrue, y_Pred):
       return K.mean(K.square(yTrue - yPred), axis=-1)

    def a(image):
       return K.mean(K.sin(image))

    def b(image):
       return K.sqrt(K.cos(image))


a_pred = a(yPred)
a_true = a(yTrue)

b_pred = b(yPred)
b_true = b(yTrue)

empirical_loss = (loss(yTrue, yPred))
a_loss = K.mean(K.square(a_true - a_pred))
b_loss = K.mean(K.square(b_true - b_pred))
final_loss = K.mean(empirical_loss + a_loss + b_loss)
return final_loss
```

However, when I train with this loss function, it is simply not converging well. What I want to try is to minimize the three loss functions separately, not together by adding them into one loss function.

I essentially want to do the second option here [Tensorflow: Multiple loss functions vs Multiple training ops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953379/tensorflow-multiple-loss-functions-vs-multiple-training-ops%20%20%20return%20K.mean(K.square(yTrue%20-%20yPred),%20axis=-1)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20def%20discrete_mass(jet_image):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mg%20=%200.5%20*%20(np.linspace(-1.25,%201.25,%2026)[:-1]%20+%20np.linspace(-1.25,%201.25,%2026)[1:])%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20me%20=%20np.tile(mg,%20(25,%201))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mp%20=%20np.tile(mg[::-1].reshape(-1,%201),%20(1,%2025))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20grid%20=%20tf.convert_to_tensor(mg,%20tf.float32)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20eta%20=%20tf.convert_to_tensor(me,%20tf.float32)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20phi%20=%20tf.convert_to_tensor(mp,%20tf.float32)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20jet_image%20=%20tf.reshape(jet_image,%20[100,25,25])%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Px%20=%20K.sum(jet_image%20*%20K.cos(phi),axis=(1,2))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Py%20=%20K.sum(jet_image%20*%20K.sin(phi),axis=(1,2))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Pz%20=%20K.sum(jet_image%20*%20tf.math.sinh(eta),axis=(1,2))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20E%20=%20K.sum(jet_image%20*%20tf.math.cosh(eta),axis=(1,2))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20PT2%20=%20K.square(Px)%20+%20K.square(Py)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20M2%20=%20K.square(E)%20-%20(PT2%20+%20K.square(Pz))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20M%20=%20K.sqrt(M2)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20M%20%20%20%20%20%20def%20discrete_pt(jet_image):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mg%20=%200.5%20*%20(np.linspace(-1.25,%201.25,%2026)[:-1]%20+%20np.linspace(-1.25,%201.25,%2026)[1:])%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20me%20=%20np.tile(mg,%20(25,%201))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mp%20=%20np.tile(mg[::-1].reshape(-1,%201),%20(1,%2025))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20grid%20=%20tf.convert_to_tensor(mg,%20tf.float32)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20eta%20=%20tf.convert_to_tensor(me,%20tf.float32)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20phi%20=%20tf.convert_to_tensor(mp,%20tf.float32)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20jet_image%20=%20tf.reshape(jet_image,%20[100,25,25])%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Px%20=%20K.sum(jet_image%20*%20K.cos(phi),axis=(1,2))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Py%20=%20K.sum(jet_image%20*%20K.sin(phi),axis=(1,2))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20K.sqrt(K.square(Px)%20+%20K.square(Py))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mass_pred%20=%20discrete_mass(yPred)%20%20%20%20%20mass_true%20=%20discrete_mass(yTrue)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pt_pred%20=%20discrete_pt(yPred)%20%20%20%20%20pt_true%20=%20discrete_pt(yTrue)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20empirical_loss%20=%20(loss(yTrue,%20yPred))%20%20%20%20%20mass_loss%20=%20K.mean(K.square(mass_true%20-%20mass_pred))%20%20%20%20%20pt_loss%20=%20K.mean(K.square(pt_true%20-%20pt_pred))%20%20%20%20%20final_loss%20=%20K.mean(empirical_loss%20+%20mass_loss%20+%20pt_loss)%20%20%20%20%20return%20final_loss) but in Keras form. I also want the loss functions to be independent from each other. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could have 3 outputs in your keras model, each with your specified loss, and then keras has support for weighting these losses. It will also then generate a final combined loss for you in the output, but it will be optimising to reduce all three losses. Be wary with this though as depending on your data/problem/losses you might find it stalls slightly or is slow if you have losses fighting each other. This however requires use of the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/). I'm unsure as to whether this actually implements separate optimiser instances, however I think this is as close you will get in pure Keras that i'm aware of without having to start writing more complex TF training regimes.

For example:

```
loss_out1 = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='loss1')(x)
loss_out2 = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='loss2')(x)
loss_out3 = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='loss3')(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=[input],
                outputs=[loss1, loss2, loss3])
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(1e-3),
          loss=['binary_crossentropy', 'categorical_crossentropy', 'custom_loss1'],
          loss_weights=[1., 1., 1.])
```

This should compile a model with 3 outputs at the end from (x) which would be above. When you compile you set the outputs as a list as well as set the losses and loss weights as a list. Note that when you fit() that you'll need to supply your target outputs three times as a list too e.g. `[y, y, y]` as your model now has three outputs.

I'm not a Keras expert, but it's pretty high-level and i'm not aware of another way using pure Keras. Hopefully someone can come correct me with a better solution!

Comment: I've made the new model with the three outputs but now I'm running into a new error " Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 3 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]" The error is made because the model expects three different inputs for each loss function. Is there a way to fix it so that three loss functions can be calculated with one input?

Comment: Hard to answer this without seeing the code. Maybe raise a new question and link to it from here? In short, you need to pass the output 3 times as a list as I said above, one for each loss. They can all be identical like I have above. Not sure you are actually having an issue where it wants 3 inputs but rather the input to the loss function, i.e. the targets, you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is only one output, few things that can be done:

1.Monitor the individual loss components to see how they vary.

```
def a_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    a_pred = a(yPred)
    a_true = a(yTrue)   
    return K.mean(K.square(a_true - a_pred))

model.compile(....metrics=[...a_loss,b_loss])
```

2.Weight the loss components where lambda_a & lambda_b are hyperparameters.

```
final_loss = K.mean(empirical_loss + lambda_a * a_loss + lambda_b * b_loss)
```

3. Use a different loss function like SSIM.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/ssim